# not retrieving data from a Blob

Tags: javascript, html5-audio

my project is about recording audio using html5.I'm saving the audio in a blob.I want to use the data in that blob to convert it to mp3 or any other format using ffmpeg,my problem is that when calling the fileName of the audio, it's giving me an error that invalid data was found when calling input.In other words, its not reading the fileName of the audio I'm recording.
here is my code for saving the fileName and downloading it:

```
 var blob = new Blob ( [ view ], { type : 'audio/wav' } );

    // let's save it locally

 // let's save it locally
    document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = 'Handing off the file now...';
    var url = (window.URL || window.webkitURL).createObjectURL(blob);
    console.log(url);
    var link = window.document.createElement('a');
    link.href = url;
    link.download = 'output.wav';
    var fileName=link.download;
    console.log(link.download);
```

my question is: why I can't retrieve the fileName of the audio file.although in the console its getting me back the name of the file, but when accessing that file it gives me no data to be found.what is going wrong??